# How to create filters for custom made Django resources?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a 'custom' made Django resources for 2 of my tables. Both the tables have one column in common (column- mask). I want to get all the values from that column and display as a list in my website.

I have a filter option in my website, where I can filter this result. But the problem is even though both the tables have the same column, the filtering condition column is different, with entirely different (format) values (Table1 column- condition, Table2 Column- format). How can I implement this / modify my code to implement this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Views.py

```
class MaskResourceView(JSONResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = 'error'
        msg = "Success"
        # Table 1 Masks
        queryset_df = Table1.objects.values_list('mask', flat=True).distinct()
        # Table 2 masks
        queryset_or = Table2.objects.values_list('mask', flat=True).distinct()
        new_mask_list = list(set(list(queryset_df) + list(queryset_or)))
        new_mask_list.sort()
        return self.render_json_response(dict(objects=new_maskset_list))
```

Comment: what is the schema of the two tables in question?

Comment: I think that one is not necessary to know right?

Comment: Because the schema of both the tables are very different and complex